# Can't install Programs Through APT

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04, laptop, dependencies

Since I last reinstalled ubuntu 16.04 I am having issues using apt. When I try (ubuntu-desktop (fixing another error), unity-tweak-tool etc) I get the error saying that there's unmet dependencies   and they will not be installed. And that I have held broken packages.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the full exact output of those commands you ran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your terminal and try the following two commands. Press enter after each one.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

You could also try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

if the first commands do not work.

Comment: Your second block of commands is wrong (must be `apt-get`, misses `sudo`) and those should rather be run in first place before the other block.

Comment: Thanks @ByteCommander. I can't tell you often I do that in the command line. Especially now that we can just use apt without the get.

Comment: Great, glad you are back up and running. :)